# DB2 database and db2_compatibility_vector

Tags: sql, db2

I created database with 
DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR = ORA

it should include NUMBER_COMPAT and VARCHAR2_COMPAT set to ON
http://goo.gl/tHSDM8

But when I try to create table with number column like NUMBER(38) it says that number is too long.
It is also case with definition of variable in pl/sql package - varchar2(32767).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain differences in how these data types are supported between Oracle database and DB2 -- they are clearly [explained in the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc-gentopic2.html?lang=en).

NUMBER(x) maps to the DECIMAL(x) data type, for which the maximum precision is 31. If you need more, use DECFLOAT(34).

The maximum size of VARCHAR data type (for which VARCHAR2 is just a synonym) is 32672 bytes.